# WebView авторизация на сайте

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Всем доброго дня. Второй день ломаю голову. Не получается произвести авторизацию и войти на сайт.
[Это демо-версия. у меня рабочая стоит точно такая же.](http://demo.userside.eu/oper/index.php?page_lang=en)

Вот что сделал в OnCreate:

```
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_commutation);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    // включаем поддержку JavaScript
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    String postData = null;
    try {
        postData = "type=login"+
                "&us_oper_login="+URLEncoder.encode("admin","UTF-8")+
                "&us_oper_pass="+URLEncoder.encode("1234", "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
    }else {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
    webView.postUrl("http://demo.userside.eu/oper/core.php?core_section=dashboard", postData.getBytes());
}
```

И при открытии активности в эмуляторе, получаю что не верно логин или пароль. Подскажите куда копать. Было подозрение, что куки не писались. Поэтому дописал: CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true).

Есть еще одна идея, тупо после загрузки страницы в onPageFinished ввести логин и пароль и нажать на кнопку. Только тут то же загвоздка ((( Кнопку не могу нажать. Поля логин и пасс вставляю, а кнопку нажать не получается:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('us_oper_login_id').value = '" + user + "';const xyz = document.getElementsByName('us_oper_pass');xyz[0].value = '" + pwd + "'; })()");
```

Помогите пожалуйста )))

Comment: По второй идее - нужно найти форму и вызвать у неё `submit()`. Пример для указанной страницы: `document.forms.form1.submit();` И был у меня ещё момент, что через `.value =` не вставлялся пароль, а только через `.setAttribute('value', 'yourPassword')`

Comment: так как у формы id нет, то делал через getElementsByClassName и form[0].submit(); - ни чего не происходит......

Comment: вот с паролем попробую. спасибо. отпишусь. в предыдущем камменте не верно написал, не getElementsByClassName , а getElementsByName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий вариант со скриптом:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (url.equals("http://demo.userside.eu/oper/index.php?page_lang=en")) {
            String login = "admin_en";
            String pass = "1234";
            String script = "javascript:(function() {" +
                    " document.getElementById('us_oper_login_id').value = '" + login + "';" +
                    " const xyz = document.getElementsByName('us_oper_pass');" +
                    " xyz[0].value = '" + pass + "';" +
                    " document.forms.form1.submit(); })()";
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                view.evaluateJavascript(script, null);
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(script);
            }
        }
    }
```